# Lost original keystore android app eclipse

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, updating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I lost my .keystore file!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

I have an app on the android market for 5 months now. I haven't updated it in probably 2 months, so yesterday I went to work coding it. I finish my coding, go to export the app and it asks for my Keystore. The only problem is that when I try the use existing keystore option, THERE ARE NONE!!! So, I go through the long process of creating a new keystore and get the application exported and try to update the app and it tells me the keystores don't match, which is true.

This is the same computer I developed the first version of the app with, using the original keystore so where did it go? How do I retrieve it? My app has 500-1,000 downloads and it's $0.99 so I really don't want to piss 500 people off by removing the app and uploading a new one.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest contacting the Google team and see if they can retrieve it for you?