# Forgot android certificate signing password 

Tags: android, certificate, google-play, digital-certificate

I have published an android app long time ago.Now i want to update it, but the problem is i have forgotten the password required for signing the app. Is there anything that can be done to recover the password?Please help me.

Comment: Consider trying harder to remember your password.  Where were you when you set it?  What were you doing?  Did you reuse an existing password?  What did you generate it from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle a lost KeyStore password in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089813/how-to-handle-a-lost-keystore-password-in-android)

Answer (score 5):

No. You can't. You lost the password, that means you have to unpublish your current app, change the package name and publish a new one with a different key and package. I just had the same problem myself and after contacting Google those were they instructions!

Their reply:

> If you've lost or changed your keystore, you'll have to publish the
>   app with a new package name and a new key. You should also update the
>   description of the original app and unpublish it. Please note that we
>   do not support the deletion of apps or the re-use of package names.

Comment: This is correct.  Google had to republish one of their own apps recently for this reason.

Comment: @Zambotron which app was that?

Comment: It isn't confirmed for sure, but it's what I suspect happened for: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=en Note the "authenticator2" in the package name.  Package names on Android play really are unique, even for google :)

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 passwords to a `certificate`, first one is just for integrity-checking and isn't secured, the second one is encrypted for security.

You can brute force the 2nd password via this tool (might take days, weeks or even months):
https://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/

The first password isn't secured, so you can reset it via this code:
https://gist.github.com/zach-klippenstein/4631307

Happy hacking!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a hack that worked!! I totally recovered my cert!