# How can I retrieve a saved keystore password from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

The new Android Studio allows us to save keystore passwords for later use.  Where are these passwords stored on my computer (OSX), and is there a way to retrieve the saved values?

[image]

**EDIT**
I am looking for the Alias password, not the Keystore password

Comment: Solution from @BasicPleasureModel is the only one that works on Linux. Need to look if there is something related for OSX and Windows

Comment: @allgood The solution for OSX is right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701932/how-can-i-retrieve-a-saved-keystore-password-from-android-studio/53746927#53746927

Answer (score 45):

On macOS the latest versions of Android Studio (tested on 3.2) store keystore/key passwords in the Keychain under the following items:

- `org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.KeystoreStep$KeyStorePasswordRequestor`
- `org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.KeystoreStep$KeyPasswordRequestor`

The former stores the password of the keystore itself, and the latter – the password to the key.

You can access them using system Keychain Access app. Locate corresponding entry and double-click it. The Account field should contain the path to your keystore or the path to the key alias within the keystore in the following form: 
`KEY_STORE_PASSWORD__/Users/username/keystorename` or `KEY_STORE_PASSWORD__/Users/username/keystorename__alias`

Click `Show password` and enter your macOS password when requested. That's it!

Comment: You are a live saver. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks Mac for secure my passwords... Thanks to you cuz' you show the correct path :)

Comment: You are a life save. Thanks!!

Answer (score 45):

#### Method 1: Read from gradle build runtime

##### Step 1: add below code to app/build.gradle

```
afterEvaluate {
    if (project.hasProperty("android.injected.signing.store.file")) {
        println "key store path: ${project.property("android.injected.signing.store.file")}"
    }
    if (project.hasProperty("android.injected.signing.store.password")) {
        println "key store password: ${project.property("android.injected.signing.store.password")}"
    }
    if (project.hasProperty("android.injected.signing.key.alias")) {
        println "key alias: ${project.property("android.injected.signing.key.alias")}"
    }
    if (project.hasProperty("android.injected.signing.key.password")) {
        println "key password: ${project.property("android.injected.signing.key.password")}"
    }
}
```

[image]

##### Step 2: from menu Build -> Generate Signed apk/bundle to start a build.

##### Step 3: open Build window located in Android Studio's bottom, lookup key store info

[image]

#### Method 2: Read from Idea persistent storage

I wrote a Idea plugin, named [RestoreKeystorePlugin](https://github.com/wangkunlin/RestoreKeystorePlugin)

##### Step 1: download jar file from [download link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wangkunlin/RestoreKeystorePlugin/master/RestoreKeystorePlugin.jar)

##### Step 2: install the plugin to Android Studio

[image]
then restart Android Studio if required

##### Step 3: select Tools -> Restore Keystore Info menu, it will show key store info on a dialog

[image]
[image]

Comment: In 2022, this is the only answer that worked from my Windows 10 PC. Android Studio has plugged a lot of the holes that previously allowed you to read raw passwords in logs. However, the plugin you created worked flawlessly. You saved my app from relisting!

Comment: Working answer in 2022

Comment: Great, works for me too!
(Windows 11, Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1)

Comment: Worked for me too July 2022 - Mac OS

Comment: THANKS!!! "In 2022, this is the only answer that worked from my Windows 10 PC"

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is uptodate, clear and easy to run. It worked for me too.

Comment: wow that really worked ! you are a life saver man !! on mac

Comment: Worked the First method on date 10 th August 2023 on Flemingo Version of Android studio.

Answer (score 41):

You can find this in the idea.log files generated by Android Studio:

Search for "Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password" and you can see the key password.

Example logs:

> 2015-11-13 10:22:48,844 [ 709463]   INFO -
>   a.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker - Build command line options:
>   [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true,
>   -Pandroid.injected.signing.st     ore.file=/Users/varun/Projects/myapp/mykey.jks,
>   -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=mykeystorepassword, -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=myalias, -**Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=mykeypassword**     , -Pandroid.injected.apk.location=/Users/varun/code/android/workspace/myapp,
>   --init-script, /private/var/folders/vk/z504nlhd6v30p7zvtgjp5sjm0000gn/T/asLocalRepo0.gradle]

Note 1: On OSX the idea.log file can be found at ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio2.0

Note 2: If you don't find the password in idea.log, then also look at the files called idea.log.1, idea.log.2 and so on.

[Source](http://techzog.com/development/android/retrieve-saved-keystore-password-android-studio/)

Comment: worked a treat, I was about to start using https://github.com/MaxCamillo/android-keystore-password-recover to brute force my keystore - you saved my bacon

Comment: Password is masked but I found correct keystore location :-)

Comment: On OSX the log files for the latest version of Android Studio (currently 2.0) can be found at ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio2.0. I found the password in idea.log.1 so you may need to check a couple of files before you find what you're after

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a better solution than bruteforcing :D

If anyone can't find the log file on OSX like me:
In Studio: Help->Show Log in Finder->open file and search ;)

Comment: What is "Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password" here? Is it your app package name?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal : This is the name of the key which stores your keystore password.

Comment: The default log file on Windows: C:\Users\UserName\.AndroidStudio2.3\system\log\

Comment: I didn't have anything in the logs, but when you attempt to `Generate a signed apk`, it will write it again in the logs. Almost sounds like a security issue, but at least, you need your master password for it to write to logs. If you see the password and remember password is checked, you can always retrieve it this way. No need for the keystore file. Tested on `AndroidStudio2.3` `cat ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio2.3/idea.log | grep password`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on AS 3.0 on Ubuntu, there are asterisks in place of password characters in logs.

Comment: Doesn't work for Android Studio 3.x. The passwords are masked with asterisks (as it should be from the very beginning). Check below working solutions for [macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53746927/648313) and [Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52190529/648313)

Comment: This works, in Windows the default location I had was C:\Users\melardev\X where X depends on Android Studio Version it may be: .AndroidStudio2.1 or .AndroidStudio3.2 or .AndroidStudioPreview3.0 or other value. The command I used was $ grep -n --color -P "signing\.(store|key)" ./.AndroidStudio2.1/system/log/*  using git bash, It showed up the files containing the passwords

Comment: @Melardev As many others already commented, this does not work on newer versions of Android Studio. It worked for you because you were using AndroidStudio 2.1

Comment: doesn't work anymore, solution from @BasicPleasureModel worked for me.

Comment: @LeosLiterak And what;s that correct location? Because I can see the password in masked :(

Comment: Sorry, this question is 5 years old and I quit Android development years ago.

Comment: this was an expolit... it was fixed. Please edit answer

Answer (score 25):

For anyone attempting keystore password recovery on more recent versions of Android Studio and Ubuntu, it seems that most documented suggestions to recover the password from logs, gradle, etc no longer work. Corneliu's excellent brute force script is great - unless you chose a 16 character password with no dictionary words in it and would like a result some time this month :) Using the Intellij security.xml solution is no longer available to retrieve saved passwords from Android Studio either, as far as I can tell.

However - having dug around a bit, Android Studio 3.1 seems to use the OS keychain in Ubuntu 18.04, so retrieving a saved keystore password is as simple as:

1. open 'Passwords and Keys' (use super key and search 'password')
2. filter results by 'android'
3. look at each entry, they will be
   something like org.jetbrains.android...KeyPasswordRequestor, and
   open each one up in turn
4. expand the password dropdown and select
   'Show password', it will look something like:
   KEY_STORE_PASSWORD__/home/pathto/keystore/keystore-name.jks@mycoolpassword

Find the keystore you're looking for and the bit after @ is your missing password. Hope that helps someone out there!

Comment: Great! It worked on OSX also. Open keychain access and filter on android

Comment: @KamenDobrev Yep, For OSX I described the details in an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701932/how-can-i-retrieve-a-saved-keystore-password-from-android-studio/53746927#53746927

Comment: Still works as of Ubuntu 23.04, but you have to search for "intellij" instead of "android"

Answer (score 13):

Gradle stores them within your project directory in a binary file. You can get them like this (from the project directory):

`strings .gradle/GRADLE_VERSION/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin | grep storePassword -A1`

(Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33624636/1982087 for the taskArtifacts.bin pointer)

Comment: if there are multiple GRADLE_VERSION's try on all of them ..it worked for me on 2.2.1 ..didn't work for 2.4

Comment: Worked for me on windows when none of the other methods did, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please explain how to get to this on windows ?

Comment: worked for me; you made me also go to the original question and upvote it too :)

Answer (score 9):

look for the log file from the date which you had signed your apk and you can find your key info there like below.

```
-Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=[store_password], 
-Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=[alias], 
-Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=[key_password]
```

you can find your log files under

> C:\Users\username.AndroidStudio[versionNum]\system\log\

Comment: as of android studio 3.0 with gradle 4.1, they are masked (passwords stored as ******)

Comment: If they marked as ***** how can we get them in android studio 3.0 and above

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem!

it makes me crazy but I found a little script that it´s saves me: https://github.com/corneliudascalu/intellij-decrypt

I think it could help you.
Good Look

Comment: It would be much better if you could show how to use that method as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code those are easy to extract, a simple way is to modify the app `build.gradle.kts` adding something like this:

```kotlin
task("helpMeOutHere") {
    doLast {
        println("Executing helpMeOutHere")
        if (project.hasProperty("android.injected.signing.store.password")) {
            println("helpMeOutHere - StorePas: ${project.property("android.injected.signing.store.password")}")
        }
        if (project.hasProperty("android.injected.signing.key.password")) {
            println("helpMeOutHere - Password: ${project.property("android.injected.signing.key.password")}")
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>() {
    dependsOn.add("helpMeOutHere")
}
```

than execute the Android Studio generate signed APK and look in the build log  for "helpMeOutHere"

be sure to remove the above snipped once you recovered your passwords