# how to recover keystore file Android

Tags: android, google-play

I had created new keystore with the existing keystore file because I had forgotten the password.
But play store is not accepting my keystore file because the new keystore file is using different SHA-1.
Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forgot Keystore password, thinking of Brute-Force detection. will it corrupt the keystore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149530/forgot-keystore-password-thinking-of-brute-force-detection-will-it-corrupt-the)

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701932/how-can-i-retrieve-a-saved-keystore-password-from-android-studio)

Comment: I had created a new keystore by using the exixting one. So the problem is not finding out the password. Google play is not accepting my new apk because the new SHA-1 certificate is not matching with the old certificate.

Comment: It will not accept the new keystore because of the new SHA-1 fingerprint. You cannot update your existing app with a different keystore. You either need to figure out the password for the old keystore, brute force it (might take decades depending on your original password's length), or upload a new app with a new package name using the new keystore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run this command for my newly created keystore( with the existing keystore file).

> keytool -list -keystore
>   C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\keystore.jks

then I got all alias with SHA-1 for the keystore file.

> Enter keystore password:
>
> Keystore type: JKS Keystore provider: SUN
>
> Your keystore contains 3 entries
>
> newkey, Oct 30, 2017, PrivateKeyEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):
>   R5:55:9V:12:5B:91:4C:01:92:D0:21:AE:A7:78:E7:9B:F3:80:8C:89 key1,
>   Sep 6, 2017, PrivateKeyEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):
>   0C:1A:B7:EE:32:B7:AF:MD:14:12:D9:44:3A:02:C6:B6:58:30:AA:E3 appkey,
>   Oct 30, 2017, PrivateKeyEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):
>   14:DB:9F:C4:00:D1:C3:34:81:A0:EE:27:8E:24:4E:68:45:AF:BM:50

So, now I have all the alias with their Certificate fingerprints (SHA1). My app was signed list time on Sep 6. 
But the problem was the password which I also have forgotten.

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31232804/2970035). As I am a window user I navigated through 
AndroidStudio>system>log>idea.
I searched in idea file created on Sep 6. Here I found the password as well as alias. 
After that, I generated my signed APK with the alias and password.

Successfully updated my APK on google play!!