# How do I change a keystore password without the original password?

Tags: keystore

Is it possible to change a keystore password without the original password?

If it is not possible, what are the other solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please Advice Needed, Lost KeyStore password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089813/please-advice-needed-lost-keystore-password)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to change the keystore password without knowing original password. Only possible solution is using brute force to break the password!