# I forgot my android apk signing pasword?

Tags: java, android, apk, keystore, keytool

I released some apks on the playstore 5 months ago. Now I finally have the time and resources to update those apps. The thing is, I have forgotten my signing password. (The keystore and key password). I remember that I set both the passwords same. I tried using the brute force attack, dictionary (wordlist) method to retrieve the password but it doesnt work. (I cant keep running the attack for a year!!) I tried using the keytool on debug.keystore but none of the passwords I remember work. I used "android" as it is the default password, it shows the SHA1, SHA256 and MD5. All I need to do is to update the apps and I cant because it needs to be signed with the same certificate. I cant just make another apk and make a new app because there are good reviews and download numbers that I want to keep. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have keystore file with you ?

Comment: Yes I do. debug.keystore file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089813/please-advice-needed-lost-keystore-password

Comment: have you check my answer below. it will help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: please accept answer if it is usefull.

Answer (score 1):

lossing key store and password you will not able to updated application on google play .

Remove old application from Google play and create new key store. create new signed apk using that key store.

if you don't remove previous application from google play than you must have to change package name(google play not allow to upload two application with same package name).

the only way is try different password what you have remember at last.