# Android - Different keystore with same passwords and alias

Tags: java, android, android-keystore

I forgot my passwords for my keystore and got the "keystore is tampered or passwords incorrect" message

I finally found the passwords using the logs but I still get the same error message.

Firstly is this because I entered the passwords too many times

Secondly If I created a new keystore with the same passwords and alias would I be able to successfully upload the app

Comment: *I finally found the passwords using the logs but I still get the same error message.* so you didn't find the password

Comment: Different KeyStore are simply different login so there is no relation between those two. For the first one, if it was blocked (don't know if there is), you should contact the support of android store to see what you can do or check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12500386/4391450)

Answer (score 0):

I guess by "upload the app" you mean publishing it in the google play store, right?

Short answer: No!

Long answer:
You need the original key to upload a new version of your app.