# How to handle a forgotten keystore password in Ionic development?

Tags: ionic-framework, certificate, keystore

Using ionic app I have released my first version. So its crossed ore than 10,000 downloads and user are using my app. Now I want to release some update with my app. So I release the unsigned apk, but when I do this step :

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

it was asking the password for `my-release-key.keystore` but I forgot the password. Please give me some solution.

I tried to create new

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

But when I release the update and upload in app store, I am getting the error last update certificate is not match with this build. When I Google it, it's because of the newly generated `my-release-key.keystore`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a lost KeyStore password in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089813/how-to-handle-a-lost-keystore-password-in-android)

Comment: Do you recall how many letters were in your keystore, and what sort of letters/case/symbols you would have used? Perhaps you can write a script to brute-force search it.

Comment: @halfer    yes i have used some my name and some number that i know...but i forgot my password ..can u help me on reterive that ??

Comment: Well, I am giving you clues to help you do it yourself. For example, can you write a script (in any programming language) to run one of the above binaries to brute-force search? If you can sensibly limit the search criteria then maybe you can find it. For example if you know your name makes up the first X letters, you may only have to try a few hundred combinations. If you know it is only lower-case, that helps too. If the letters after your name are just digits, that helps. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

According to this SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6089813/1783706) accepted answer there is no way to retrieve a lost keystore password.

But in some of the more recent non-accepted answers people claim to have found solutions to retrieve lost keystore passwords. Maybe you want to check those out?

If you don't get a hold of the lost password the only thing you can do is to re-submit (unpublish current app and publish a new one with the same title and description) your app with a newly created keystore. If that is the case, be sure to store your password in a secure location :)

Comment: re- release measn ?.. should i need to make my app unpublish and with same name with same package name can i release it again...

Comment: so will it be a update or new app to users....becuase my app is more than using by 10,000 ppl...so how can i release the new app without the update ?

Comment: I think you will just have to hope your users find their way back to the new app. As stated in the comments of the linked to SO question.  I understand that it is a huge headache, so take a look at the more recent answers and see if you find a solution that works for you in any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can find the password in the following temp Gradle file:

```
<YourProjectRoot>\platforms\Android\.gradle\<version>\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin
```

Open that file with a plain text editor and search for "password".  You should see it there in plain text.  Please note it may have some special characters around it, but you will probably recognize the characters you used for the password originally.

I hope this helps!