# I have forgot android studio Keystore password ,how to upload updates to previously published application on google play store?

Tags: android-studio, console, passwords, keystore, jks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buhLE.png)

OLD :-> B8:F5:26:B4:87:59:A8:F3:19:80:4B:3A:65:75:43:D0:C4:7D:FD:12
NEW :-> 08:7C:A0:5D:6C:36:AA:FE:6D:13:E4:DA:B6:BB:C7:CA:5A:20:EF:30

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a lost KeyStore password in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089813/how-to-handle-a-lost-keystore-password-in-android)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystore-password-recovery

Answer (score 0):

Try Brute Force!

https://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/wiki/HowTo

Using a list of 5-10 possible words from memory, it recovered my password in <1 sec.

If you are lucky there may be a small chance to find your password in the gradle temporary file

```
..Project\.gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin
```