# Lost Android keystore password But app is signing using google signing method

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, android-app-bundle, android-app-signing

My friend's app is live on google play store using app bundle and Google Signing method.

Now he want to update new version of app but unfortunately he lost keystore password

How he can update this app

I know there is no possible way to recover keystore or it's password but I think if your are using **Google play signing method to punish app** then it is possible but don't know how can do this we Exact Process of it.

we search lots on internet but not received any solution.
Thank you for help in advance..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle a lost KeyStore password in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089813/how-to-handle-a-lost-keystore-password-in-android)

Comment: @KanzariyaHitesh thank you for help But I know you can upload new app with new keystore this is one solution But I think If you are using google play signing method to live app then you can restore your keystore and password please correct if I am wrong

Comment: Yaa you are right but check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089880/10967323).

Comment: @KanzariyaHitesh I don't want to unpublish existing app I think we can do without unpublishing existing app

Comment: show all answer please.

Comment: Review the steps in `Lost or compromised upload key?` in https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Your "friend" can reset the upload key by contacting the Play Developer support. All the instructions are on that page: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en