# Lost Alias key password in android studio 3.1.3

Tags: android-studio, key, signing, android-keystore, change-password

I have generated a signed apk for an application two months back. Now I want to release an update for the app, for which I tried generating signed apk after making the required changes. But, I get the 'Cannot recover key' error. I checked the password in idea.log file, but it has been hidden to ********. I got my Keystore password from taskHistory.bin, but I am not able to find the Key password(Alias key).

Is there any way to reset the key password without entering the old key password ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle a lost KeyStore password in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089813/how-to-handle-a-lost-keystore-password-in-android)

Comment: No, it didnt help @MarkusKauppinen. I remembered my keystore password, but not the Alias key password.