# I'm trying to export my Android app update for signing, and my key isn't automatically showing up, where do I look to find it?

Tags: android, macos, distribution, code-signing

Ok so I have a few apps on the Android market that are very similar, just targeting different languages. When I made the apps, I just went through and created the key stores based on the langage they were for, and didn't pay a whole lot of attention as to where I was putting them.

Now I'm going through trying to update the apps, and there are a couple apps whose keystore didn't automatically populate as found by Eclipse.

This isn't a matter of me losing my computer, or losing my hard drive, I just don't know where to look for the files I need. What is the key's filename extension? Is there a certain place it would be stored by default? I have several time machine backups I can go to, where should I look?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know any information that might be stored in the key, such as organization, owner or key name?

Comment: Yes I do. I've tried searching for the key name via spotlight, but it didn't come up with anything. Then again, it didn't produce anything when I was searching by name for a key that I still have...so I'm just not understanding something about where they are being saved

Comment: Have you tried grepping for it? grep -r "<search term>" /* I would pick a directory lower than /* though.

Answer (score 0):

In all probability, the *.keystore* files (the key) might have been moved which is why Eclipse isn't able to populate them by default. Try doing a search for *.keystore.

If not, just create a new one. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: The problem is that unless I sign it with the same exact key, I can't publish app updates. So I'm desperately trying to find that keystore. I tried searching for files with that extension, and it came up with nothing...

Comment: hmm, turns out that you'd have to absolutely find the keystore to publish updates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do