# Error while updating an android app in market site

Tags: android, google-play, apk, keystore

i have recently published my app in android market site. After a month i have added and removed some features in it. By this i have added a map feature and i created a new build using a new keystore, i tried to update my app but it shows an error as follows

```
"The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version."
```

How to resolve this issue. How to know my former keystore values. i use to give the same Organisation name, Country etc but i think i have changed the expiry year. How to update my app with the new keystore

Pls give me some suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ONLY update an existing app with the same certificate ("keystore") as original app. There is NO WAY around it.

This has been already asked many times. See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+update+market+lost+certificate)

Answer (score 0):

You must have created 2 files when u uploaded your application. One file is .apk file for market and another file which is the keystore.

When u provide update to the existing app, you'll need the keystore. When u export your project in Eclipse u need to say from existing key and browse the keyfile u created when u used previously.

If you have lost your previous key file, [then read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do). It'll help you.