# Not able to upload updated app in android market

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

I have uploaded my app in the market. But I had forgot the Keystore and alias password.

By the time i guess correct, the alias option disappeared. So i had to create a new alias and password. I gave the alias password as the keystore password.

What do i have to do? I cant upload.

Please give me specific instructions at what to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+update+market+lost+certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do your best to recall your password, there is no other way to update your app instead of uploading it as a new one. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do).