# Android Keystore Rebuild? is it possible

Tags: android

Actually, I have lost my keystore of some of my apps. But I know the exact information which was into that keystore, I used same info written in .txt file for every keystore.

Is there any way to restore, rebuild by using the info were into that keystore?

Any ways to recover keystore?

You help will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No. Even if you input the same information, the keytool will generate a new private/public key pair, and that is the part that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can re-create keystore with the data you have, it seems Android doesn't accept it. Here is SO discussion on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do).