# Extract Keystore file from apk file

Tags: android, keystore

i am update my android app to google play shop it shows error same signed certificate previous version.but, my previous version app keystore signed file is missing and i am upload another new keystore signed try to update but not working shows a same error!,searching related for error more details for not understand and extract the keystore file from previous version apk file is possible? or not posssible? or what i am doing for update my application to google playshop,Please can any one guide me...!

Thanks..!

Comment: see this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to update the same app if you lose the keystore. One alternative which may be bad would be to upload it as a new app with a different package name.