# How to create the duplicate keystore for Android application

Tags: android, duplicates, keystore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I lost my .keystore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)
>   [Android: I lost my android key store, what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do)

I want to update my Android application was already uploaded(existing) in 
the Google play, but I have missed my key store already created.

I know all the details of old keystore (alias,psw,name,validity year,country code etc) may I can create the duplicate key for that

It is possible one? this duplicate key will accepted by google play for update my app?

Comment: Without the keystore file, u can never update your app, sorry!
The only thing u could do is remove the previous app from the market and put a new one (with new key).

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/a/4322386/735675