# The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version while uploading apk on market

Tags: android, google-play, keytool, android-keystore

I have created an application and published on android market. now i want to publish its 2nd version. the few thing i want to make clear:

1. I have kept same package name.
2. I do not have previous keystore cause i changed the windows so keystore deleted and i do not have backup of that keystore.

Now what i should is there any way to retrieve keystore  from previous apk.

i know there is so many answers on stackoverflow some are saying possible and some are saying impossible.

please need exact solution.

Comment: I think without old keystore. You can't upload your application into market. You should change your package name and upload it into market with new `keystore` file.

Comment: Is it possible to extract certificate from previous apk?

Comment: No you can't. I've also faced the same problem. So, i just change the package name and upload it.

Comment: @mishucn, if it's possible to extract a private key from a signed packages, then the whole package signing scheme breaks down into being a pointless ritual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, You have to have the same **keystore** file which you have used to upload the 1st version of application on android market.

> **If you have lost this keystore file then you can't provide update to this application.**

Just read this [Publishing App on Market.](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html) The same problem i've also faced. So, i just change the package name and upload it into market with new keystore. So, keep the **Keysotre** file safely. See these existing questions which is related to your queries -

1. [Android: I lost my android key store, what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4459719/940096)
2. [I lost my .keystore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4322367/940096)

Answer (score 0):

it's imposible bcs when we are creating key store that is for publishing our application to android market to the most first time.now say if u need to update it latter on u need to create updation on existing key store.in ur case u need to make another newly key store and make it sign again and put that signed apk & key store for future reference..that's only the posiblity