# The apk should be signed by the same certificate as the previous version

Tags: android

I was developing on a computer which i no longer have access to(i have the backup of keystore file). I had used Eclipse and created my keystore in it for my 1.0 release. Now i want to release the 2nd version and used the backup keystore in my new computer. I signed my apk with the backup keystore in eclipse and tried to publish the updated version in google play but getting this error:

```
"The apk should be signed by the same certificate as the previous version".
```

Can anybody help me in this.

**Note** : I have incremented the version name and version code in the manifest file for 2nd version.

Comment: Check http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link:

[The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version while uploading apk on market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084566/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version-while)

Same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs android_app
```

on the previous and new app and check `CERT.RSA` filename for each, to make sure that you are using the correct keystore.

check also https://stackoverflow.com/a/4843282/1434631