# Have to upload new apk because keystore is corrupted, How to send free apk to users?

Tags: android

As my keystore file is corrupted I need to upload an apk with different signature.
This is a paid app and about 100 users have already bought the app.
By the grace of God, is there a way to make the new app free for those users or email apk to them or else what is the way out in this condition ?.
**Any suggestion may save my life(job)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unfortunate, but when you lose your keystore, or the password to your keystore, your application cannot be accessed. The only thing you can do is resubmit your app to the market under a new key.
ALWAYS backup up your keystore and write the passwords down in a safe location.

You may refer to link below:
[Android: I lost my android key store, what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do)
And one piece of advice: Edit your current app info and write description that current app is no longer in use.For the existing users; manage on your side to include their current subscriptions/purchases.