# How to get keystore file from signed apk

Tags: android, apk, fingerprint, android-keystore

I have already signed my apk with default debug.keystore key.But unfortunately my system destroyed,Now I need to get the key store from the already signed apk.

to replace with old apk with new apk.

I have MD5,SHA fingerprints with.But i could make them as keystore to sign the apk.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can get keystore like this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: I lost my android key store, what should I do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do)

Answer (score 16):

```
unzip -p Name-of-apk.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA | keytool -printcert
```

is what I used.

It produces information such as the owner, issuer, serial number, valid through, certificate finger prints, signature algorithms and version.

Comment: So If I use same information then I will get same keystore file? with same SHA?

Comment: @PratikButani, hi. Could you figure out how ti use this information to generate a keystore file or sign an .apk file?

Comment: I have got the information . Now how to get it as key store

Comment: You cannot. The whole point of a keystore is to prevent people who haven't got it to pretend they are you. Unfortunately you probably need to make a new keystore and lose the possibility to smoothly update the app.

Comment: This is very useful to find keystore information. Thank you