# Is it possible to recreate a new android keystore using my old keystore details?

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore, android-update-app

I want to give an updation to my existing app. Now i am using a new system for developing, the problem is that my keystore is in my old system .Is it possible to recreate the same keystore in my new system, i know all the details of my old keystore firstname,lastname,alias,password etc..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are having old keystore then you should go with that one instead of creating new one.

Comment: I don't have my old keystore, i know only the details i given to create that.. problem is now i am developing using new system.

Comment: No, it's not possible to create new keystore.
System does not matter you should keep a copy of the keystore as a backup. If you are not having any copy then it's not possible to reproduce keystore file. 
According to android standards every application is signed with unique keystore file and that keystore file is required throughout life cycle of that application. If keystore is deleted by mistake then you should try system recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation says that

> In general, the recommended strategy for all developers is to sign all
>   of your applications with the same certificate, throughout the
>   expected lifespan of your applications.

You should check this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#strategies).

In your case if you create new `keystore` for your existing app on google play. Google play console will prompt error that same package exist already.
So you must get your old `Keystore` for further updates of your application.

[For your case check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459831/2022000)