# I have lost .jks file. Can i publish new app with same package name and application name

Tags: android

My APP has around 10k downloads and i lost .jks file.
Now i have found it's not possible to update the new version.

I just want to know how can i publish it as a new app with same name and application id and inform old users to download new app.

Comment: you need to unpublish the current version first in order to reupload with the same apk name I think

Comment: I think you can unpublish the current version from play store and reupload you new apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android officially doesn't allow to recover your keystore (.JKS). There are some 3rd party tools which says that you can recover it.

[Android: I lost my android key store, what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do)

Coming to your answer we CANT publish new app with same APPLICATION ID. Also from same account we CANT publish new app with same APP NAME, you have to use some postfix your app name. Like if old app name is TEST then Google allows you "TEST app", "TEST.(dot)" etc.

Comment: is there any other way i can use same app name.

Comment: You have to create NEW android publisher account. You have to loose $25. :D