# Android Studio keystore not found

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-keystore, android-signing

I have an Android project published on google play, signed with my previous installation of Windows and Android studio.

Due to formatting the PC (the computer is the same), I lost the .jks file to sign the application.
If I have the key store password with which to sign this app.

1. Can I re-sign the app with the same keys as before?
2. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?
3. I would like to update the app, instead of having to issue a new
   one.

**UPDATE:**

I have copy to  keys ssh

[image]

Comment: If you lost the .jks file you're doomed!!! I would suggest create a new app

Comment: you can not do anything to recover from the apk or something?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I had this problem a while back, and the app could be updated (I learned the hard way!).  You should probably accept Amit Vaghela's answer, since it is correct.  I wish you the best.

Comment: Nope. .jks file contains the signature of the app. You'll need it when you want to release a new update to play store. reverse engineering the .jks file from apk is impossible.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, my worst fears are realized. a greeting

Comment: No backup?! Really?? Pendrives are very cheap nowadays, you have no excuse.

Comment: When that happens GGWP. Btw there is still a possibility to recover a formatted PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to restore it via deleted files restoring tools, but it failed. **So, there is no other way**: you should issue another application.

Generally, the only advise that exists on keystores: "always back it up!"

The only way is that you can **create an app with a new package name upload it to store and remove the old app**.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do