# Can I retrieve keystore info from an old apk and use it to update with a new apk?

Tags: android, keystore

I published an app on the play store about two years ago,
The computer I created it on is long gone, so I don't have any keystore info.

I have a new app now, just done in android studio, I was wondering, is there
any way I could get the correct keystore info from the old apk and use it in 
the keystore for the new app, then I could update the old app, can this be done?
Instead of having to create a new app on the play store, lose ratings etc.

It's annoying that we can't download our apk's from Google Play Dev Console.

Comment: Look into the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11331951/1061944

Comment: All I need are the Alias, Key password and store password?
I mean I don't have keystore from the old app, but the app is published.
I was wondering if I could download the old apk some how then get the
keystore info from that to sign my new app, then upload the new app
over the old one, basically update the old app with the new one, using
the old app's keystore info.

Comment: Didn't get it. You need aliases ?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39545833/2826147)

Comment: God I'm screwed