# How to retrieve Key Password from a keystore in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, keystore, android-keystore

Some other person already uploaded an app in play store.And i have started as new project with same package name.And i got an old keystore from dev. But there is no keystore password. Is there any possibility to get keystore password from an keystore? I have followed this link;
https://github.com/tonytlwu/android-keystore-password-recover

I got an Found Alias.

Comment: Have a look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/21920961/6154719

Comment: Am getting key alias and all..But not getting password from this tool