# Android Release KeyStore create custom

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, sha1, android-keystore

I have developed and released an application few years ago and i missed my released keystore. i tried with new keystore but google play avoiding the apk.
but i able to find the following details of released apk.

> Certificate fingerprints:
>
> ```
>      MD5:  xxx
>      SHA1: xxx
>      SHA256:xxx
>      Signature algorithm name: xx
>      Version: xx
> ```

can i able to create an custom keystore form above details?

my default keystore sha1 key and md5 keys are not matching with above sha1 and md5 keys.

appreciate any answer.. thank you

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do) answer

Comment: also check this answer [I Lost my .keystore File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

Comment: thanks for info @ELITE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry brother if you forgot or deleted your keystore , there is no guaranteed way of updating your app or making a custom one in your case.