# Lost APK signing key

Tags: android, android-studio

I have published my app on Google play a few days​ ago and since then i had to uninstall and reinstall my Android studio. Now I don't have the signing key anymore. Is is possible to make the exact same or i can't update my anymore on Google play?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: I lost my android key store, what should I do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I lost my .keystore file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

Answer (score 0):

Signing key is a jks file independent from AS.
If you have lose that file, you can't update your app anymore.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do)

> You can create a new keystore, but the Android Market wont allow you
>   to upload the apk as an update - worse still, if you try uploading the
>   apk as a new app it will not allow it either as it knows there is a
>   'different' version of the same apk already in the market even if you
>   delete your previous version from the market
>
> Do your absolute best to find that keystore!!
>
> When you find it, email it to yourself so you have a copy on your
>   gmail that you can go and get in the case you loose it from your hard
>   drive!

You have to save the jks file in a directory different from the Android Studio one. It is not related to Android Studio

I suppose if you change pakage name and app name it shouldn't give you any problem on google play console. But you can't update that one, sorry. Try your best to recover the jks file!

Comment: Oh! I guess changing package name works tho! The thing is that my app got successful so fast! It has 7K+ downloads in 5 days! And its pretty new as I said! I can't just leave it not updated! Is there anyway to update it ? :(

Comment: Wow this is a problem! I suppose if you change pakage name and app name it shouldn't give you any problem on google play console. But you can't update that one, sorry. Try your best to recover the jks file!

Comment: Yes I know. As I said, try your best to recover that file! Don't you have saved  the jks file in a directory different from the Android Studio one?

Comment: Try to search in your java jre or jdk (not sure) bin folder. You can use the search function there and search for the file. Maybe you just didn't remember your installation location