# Lost old keystore, need to sign the app with new keystore

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I lost my .keystore file!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

I have lost the old keystore for Android app published on Market. I don't want to republish it with different package.

1. Can I get old certificate through signed original old apk?
2. Can I signed the apk with multiple keystore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, public-private key security mechanism are setup specifically to avoid being able to reconstruct the certificate.

If you've lost your keystore then you're basically stuck.

Always backup your keystore and store it in a secure place (or places).