# what should I do when I lose my old keystore?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I lost my .keystore file!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

I had lost my app.keystore of version 1.0 and I want to upgrade this app to 1.1 though I have that apk only of version 1.0 now How can I upload new version in android market.

Comment: And what is your question exactly. What you want to know ?. You want to know about lost old keystore or you want to know how to upload new version of app in market..!!

Comment: for lost key store, no chance, just creating new application.

Comment: I want to know about how to upgrade new version in case of lost key store?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To upload your new version  of your app to android market you need to change one of the two attributes in your manifest.

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

here version code refers to the minor changes to your app code.

and version name refers to the major releases of your code.

cheers..

Comment: he will not be able to update the .apk on market since old and new versions should be signed with the same key

Comment: Yes you are right Vladimir thanks for correcting me.