# Eclipce deleted my keystore

Tags: android, restore, keystore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I lost my .keystore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

i was working in eclipce yesterday and when i created a new Android Project it had liked all dokuments files to the project, so i deleted the project and eclipce deleted prettu much of my computer so i restored windows but today when i was back on and was going to export a android project i realiced that my keystore and my kaystone that i had backed up on another hard drive had been deleted.

After some googeling i have read that i can't create a new or restore a keystore froma apk file. And i very concered becuse i have a appp that cost money and i don't want do disapoint my costumers.

So my question is am i scruwed? or can i do somethin and what?
ThX
Sorry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to restore files from the trash (the basket on the desktop). It doesn' matter, what had deleted files, in WIndows they are in the basket some time after. Only for god's sake, dont create new files before it!