# I have not keystore Certificate, Private key for upgrade app in Android market

Tags: google-play, upgrade

Hello All I have not keystore - Certificate, Private key for upgrade old app in Android market, But I want to upgrade my old app with new changes. Please suggest any trick for upgrade it. I dont need to change my original app packege. I want to upgrade with same package. Please help me. Thank You!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but could it be that you have: 1. An app in the play store. 2. you have lost the keystore you used for this app and 3. you want to update the app?

Comment: yes sir i want to update app. please help me

Comment: @Nanne If you have any idea for upgrading app in Google play without using old key then please suggest me.

Comment: There is no option I'm afraid, see the multiple duplicates on this site alone, google and/or google groups.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I lost my .keystore file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)