# Lost keystore Android

Tags: android, apk, keystore, android-keystore

I have an app on Google Play and I want to provide a new version with updates, but unfortunately I've lost the keystore (yes, I'm an idiot).

I know that I need to use the same key to upload the new version, is there a way to fix this, for example create a new key and modify the SHA1 using the SHA1 from the other key which I've lost?

Thank You.

Comment: No, you can't do that. Once you loose your keystore you can't update the app on the play store.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I lost my .keystore file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

Comment: Great question @pagooli

Answer (score 3):

If you lost your keystore then there is no way that you can update the app in play store (it will cause a signature error)! The only way is that you can create an app with a new package name upload it to store and remove the old app.