# Android lost keystore file

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

I found alot of topics with the same problem but they always lost their password. I have the password still in my KeyPass but I have lost my keystorefile. Is it possible to restore it with help of the password or anything else? Google Play doesn't let me update my app :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lost keystore Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677826/lost-keystore-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [I lost my .keystore file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do to update the app once you lose the keystore file. Your next best option is to just release the update as a new app and inform as many of your users as you can.

Answer (score 1):

not possible. if keystore file lost nothing can be done

Answer (score 0):

No you must need that same key store to update your app. Other wise you need to create new keystore and upload it as new app by changing projects package name in manifest file.

Comment: @Downvoter Can you tell me reason why you down voted it? Add comment if you expecting any..

Answer (score 0):

I thought I lost my keystore file too.  Turns out, using Windows operating system, the keystore files were put into a virtualized folder for security purposes.  All my keystore files were in there.  That folder is off limits to explorer for some reason so searching for .keystore turned up nothing.  The only way I found it was to point explorer to the directory used when executing the original keytool generate command.  When you do that, there is a button on the top of the explorer window which says 'compatibility files'.  Click that and the keystore files appear.  Hope this helps someone.