# How to upload new version of app in play store and I lost my .keystore file

Tags: android, android-keystore, google-play

I need to upload a new version of Android application in to the play store.

I lost my .keystore file, but I have LICENSE KEY of that app.

**My License key is like:**
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAkjRWzxfdpt35luHtfNLk+hcw4j/WVidSva0C6yN+9KP1LILMuhsathcEV9dMqEvDeG+hllK5H+38N3J6zidRR3uIBnjPOyy82AQ/BOkrndlcnIqmX4c0rDVzziwk2J2BxIahg6jndfHh+ghNOVcS+Q8nc51Kt+8CJztEta57EPEQIDAQAB

Now how can I upload the new version of app in to the play store.

I do not want to upload this as a new app.

Comment: You can't, unless you can break that encryption.  This has been discussed many times before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I lost my .keystore file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you can't. License key will not help.
Post your application as the new one.

Answer (score 1):

If there is absolutely no way for you to recover your old keystore file (the whole thing), then I'm sorry to say you cannot update your app on Google Play with the same package name.

You will have to change the package name of your app and sign + export the app with a brand new keystore. (I highly recommend you e-mail it to yourself for safe keeping. I literally just lost mine last night and would've been screwed if I didn't have that e-mail)

After that, update your store listing of the "old app" to direct users to your newly uploaded app (the one signed with new key store/new package name). Eventually you can un-publish the "old app" when you feel enough users have migrated to your new app.

Hope this helps, always keep a backup ;)