# how to retrieve lost key store file if lost

Tags: android, android-keystore

My friend have an app on Play store. Today my friend upload new apk and later he found that key store is not there on the local PC.

Is there way where key store can be downloaded from play store?

We need key store any how... is there way where we can retrieve it?

Currently what we are doing is, Data recovery for todays morning.

Comment: Once you loose your keystore, you're screwed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Reference from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4322386/1318946)

> Faced the same problem. I was trying to restore it via deleted files
>   restoring tools, but it failed. So, there is no other way: you should
>   issue another application.
>
> Generally, the only advise that exists on keystores: always backup it!

Edited:

I suggest you always keep this type of important files in `GMail` or with `Project Source`, that will be better for you.

Comment: this is what I suggested mine friend now... but Google should have some way to get it... this is ridiculous...

Comment: `You are right` but there is no way. I have surf so many times.

Comment: @FahimParkar  It's not ridiculous.  It's secure.  What is ridiculous is that your friend did not back up such a critical file!

Comment: @Simon : I agree, but for some reason if it gets deleted then how can we recover?