# apk cannot upload to google play keystore error

Tags: android, keystore

I have deleted my keystore  now I have updated my apps and want to sign apk I have created another keystore  and signed my application with that  when I upload my app it gives me error  your apk is signed with different key. Now how to resolve this issue any body help ?

Comment: No. It's not possible. You must built new `.apk` with the older `keystore`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keystore is meant to prevent unauthorised updating of the app. If you don't have it (and its password), you can't update your app.

Unpublish the old app and publish a new one. It will probably require a different package name as well.

PS: Backup the keystore and your code this time.