# "An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed" error on APK install

Tags: android, apk, signature, android-install-apk, android-keystore

I have attempted to install an apk to my phone with an app that I already have installed. I have changed the version number however the issue is clearly down to the original signature of the app.

The app itself was originally developed by another company so I do not have the original signature for this? Do I need the original keystore file to allow for this?

Also it is unlikely the external company will still have the original keystore file - if this is the case & I cannot use the original key what is the next step from this?

Obviously i'd like users of the app to be able to 'upgrade' the app through Google Play without directly uninstalling the app manually themselves first.

Can anyone provide a solution ideally without the original keystore file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I lost my .keystore file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't upgrade with new keystore as @orip said.

You could ask your developer to send you keystore file. Otherwise you will have to change package name, sign with a new keystore and upload as a new application.

Comment: I was afraid you would say that - probably a long shot but I found a folder called 'META-INF' within the Android apk file that has 3 files named :-

MANIFEST.MF, SKEY.RSA & SKEY.SF
- would these of any use (i guess not just wondered as its unlikely i will be able to get the original .keystore file)

Comment: keystore is generated separately and (usually) not stored in the same directory as your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need the original keystore. As far as I know, without it you can't upgrade or upload a new version to the Play store, you'll always have to uninstall and reinstall.