# android - Lost keystore file but have alias and password

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, apk, keystore

I want to update my application but I can not because I lost my keystore file, but i have the keystore alias and password. help me please

Comment: possible duplicate of [I lost my .keystore file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

Answer (score 1):

If you lost your keystore you cannot upgrade your app anymore. You need to republish your app with a new package name.

Answer (score 0):

It's problem here for you.
If you lost your keystore then there is no way that you can update the app in play sore( it will cause a signature error )! The only way is that you can create an app with a new package name upload it to store and remove the old app.
Thanks