# Create debug.keystore with specific MD5,SHA1

Tags: android, md5, sha1

I don't know what is happened to my debug.keystore buti realized it changes. when I want to update my app i face this error:"An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed.". I don't want to delete the current app on device and then install the new one. I already extract MD5 and SHA1 from my current app, I am wondering can i create debug.keystore by these specific MD5 and SHA1 ? 
sorry for my bad English,thanks

Comment: "I am wondering can i create debug.keystore by these specific MD5 and SHA1 ?" -- not realistically. It would take you far less time to copy your data for this app off to your development machine, uninstall and reinstall the app, then copy the data back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I lost my .keystore file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)