# Android - change SHA1 fingerprint on Google Play

Tags: android, fingerprint

I had my keystore saved in my PC, but one day my hard disk died and the PC overheated because of too much dust, so I had to reinstall Windows completely, and lost the keystore...

Is there any possible way to update my application on Google Store with a new keystore or somehow get the SHA1 fingerprint from the old one, or something? Anything??

Comment: You can publish an update with a new keystore, but all your users have to uninstall previous version & install the new one

Comment: I can't submit any update because it was built with a new keystore (a new SHA1 fingerprint). Should I consider deleting my app from Google Play completely and uploading it again but with the new keystore?

Comment: "and lost the keystore" -- restore it from your backup. You *do* back up your computer, right?

Comment: I just checked the entire external hard disk for backups and apparently, I have saved absolutely everything expect that file.. I can't believe this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I lost my .keystore file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you're asking isn't possible. I tried this myself, and had to create a new application on the Google Play Store due to the [what is mentioned in the Google Developer Docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> **Warning**: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure
>   place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish
>   an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your
>   app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since
>   you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.