# transfered app, updating with react-native app, what do I need for android?

Tags: android, react-native

I have been transfered an app and I am releasing an update using react-native, what do I need to be able to get the same signing key?

The original user told me the alias and password?  Is this enough or do i need the actual signing file, if I am supposed to create the file do I need to answer all the questions in the same way to get the same signing key?

Thanks for any help

Comment: he has to send you the file. Or else you can't update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the actual `.keystore` file itself (with password and alias) as you will not be able to re-generate it, even using the same values for each of the parameters with the `keygen` tool. Without it you won't be able to publish any updates to the Play Store. This applies regardless of using React Native or otherwise as has been discussed [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file).

From [the React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html):

> Once you publish the app on the Play Store, you will need to republish
>   your app under a different package name (losing all downloads and
>   ratings) if you want to change the signing key at any point. So backup
>   your keystore and don't forget the passwords.