# Google Play Developer Console - Android Development - Keystore

Tags: android, keystore

I'm an administrator of a company's Google Play management console. And there are already several APPs in production. Yesterday I received the request to provide the keystore for a new APP that is about to be released, but I could not find it. Where can I get the Keystore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keystore contains the key required to sign the applications before submitting them to Google Play.
It is supposed to be kept securely as per the Android guidelines https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-key

You need to find the last person who built and signed an Android app. Most likely it's a developer but that depends on how your company is managed. It can also be handled by a continuous integration server if release builds are automated.

Comment: Hi, Ika. Thanks for the answer. Got it. All of the company's APPs were developed by a single developer, who lost Keystore. What should I do?

Comment: There's no way around it as stated by many other posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file .You have to find the keystore.

Comment: Got it. Thank you! I'll search.