# How to update an app on play store without the original keystore?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an android app from a long time ago, and I remade it from scratch. I lost the original keystore so I cannot update the app on play store? What is the best way to proceed? Create a new one and delete the old? Keep the old one with a link to the new one in the description?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I lost my .keystore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update the original application without the keystore. I would recommend that you update the Play Store page for your original application and link it to your new one so that you can keep some of your existing users. Make sure to make it clear in both the title and description that the application is outdated and not being updated. Delete the old one after you feel like you've rebuilt your user base.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and ended up finding my key.  You cannot update the app at all in play store.  you can't even use the same package name.  email yourself the keys next time to have them in a safe place.