# The private key does not match the certificate we know for this app

Tags: flutter, google-play, keytool

I uploaded an app to google play store a few years ago. It was written by someone else.
Now I want to update the app with a new version I created.
I updated the version code and version names, also I checked that the applicationId is the same one.
But I can't find the jks file.
What can I do? I don't want to make a new app because the old one has many active users.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't update the app without the key.

check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43443503/12156637

You can try contacting the support of play store but you have a very small chance of getting what you want