# My application key is missing , Application is in the store , Can i give the users an update

Tags: android

I want to release a new version of an existing application on the Play Store.

Problem : Key is missing

Is there a way that i can add an update on the play store for the existing application.

Does Play Store provide a way for the applications to be uploaded whose keys are missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I lost my .keystore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en