# Is there are any way to publish an App update without having previous signed keystore file?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-keystore, google-developers-console

Currently, I am working on an Android app which has already published on the app store. Now I want to publish app update with some extra features but the problem is now I don't have the previously signed keystore file.

Is there any way to **publish app update without having previously signed keystore file?**

Comment: note: if you use Google to sign your app you may be able to convince them of your identity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46084757/4435270

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've lost your keystore **you'll have to publish the app with a new package name and a new key**.

You should also update the description of the original app and unpublish it. Please **note** that users are allowed **unlimited reinstalls** of each application distributed via Google Play, an application will remain available to users that have already installed it even after it has been **unpublished**.

Currently we do not support the deletion of apps or the re-use of package names. Unfortunately, there is nothing else we can do to assist you further with this matter.

For new apps, Google can generate your app signing key. Google uses to authenticate your identity.

you can Contact [google support team](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs) 
Make sure to attach the `upload_certificate.pem` file.

hope this helps.

Comment: @user2881604 did you find this solution usefull ? need any help?

Comment: Thanks, If I publish it as a new version, Is there any way to inform about app update to the previous users??

Comment: @user2881604 no that want be done.you can use mail or send user msgs to make them know about your new app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do so. All you can do is publish new app and be very careful with the keystore  file from now on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your Keystore but forgot the alias, you can try to 
[Recover Aliases inside an Android KeyStore](http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/listing-aliases-inside-an-android-keystore-file-with-keytool/)

In case you don't have your keystore file :

You must use the previously used certificate to sign your app if you want to upload an updated version to the market. If you use a new certificate to sign your app and try to upload it as a new version, it will fail. If you upload it as a new application, the existing users will not be informed of the update.

Answer (score 0):

**IF YOU USE GOOGLE APP SIGNING**, there is a chance you can still update your app under the same package name.

With google app signing, Google ultimately signs your app. Your key is only used to verify your identity. Meaning if you can convince Google of your identity, they can modify it to accept your new upload key.

See the bottom of this [help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) (below is an excerpt).

> ### Lost or compromised private keys
>
> If you're enrolled in Google Play App Signing, you can reset your upload key if:
>
> - You lost your private key, or
> - Your private key has been compromised
>
> Note: Resetting your upload key will not affect the app signing key that Google Play uses to re-sign APKs before delivering to users.
>
> #### Step 1: Generate a new private key and upload certificate
>
> #### Step 2: Contact our support team