# Android Keystore alias missing

Tags: android, keystore, sha, android-keystore

A few months ago i uploaded a Android App to the App store which i singed with my keystore and an alias. (app1 for example)
Some times later now we decide to release a part as a new independent application.
So we used the same keystore file with an different alias. (app2 for example)

Now the problem is, that we forgott to safe the Keystore file, after the new alias was generated.

So we STILL have the .keystore file and the password, but there is only the key for the alias app1 and no alias for app2.
When we try to generate an new Keystore with the alias app2 its always different than the application in the Android Store

So is it possible to regenerate the alias with the SAME .keystore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I lost my .keystore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)

Comment: No, i dont lost my .keystore file. I still have it and still got the password for it. I just dont have the alias i need in the file

Comment: It is exactly the same to lose the alias than to lose the keystore: You can't regenerate the same key

Comment: That was my Question, if its the same or if there is a possibility to regenerate it. But if its the same we need to find a soulition to restore the file

Comment: Right now I'm experiencing the same issue.