# you uploaded an apk for android app bundle that is signed with a restricted certificate?

Tags: android, google-play

I have apk, my working pc is damaged and I have lost all source file. When uploading app to playstore it says:

you uploaded an apk for android app bundle that is signed with a restricted certificate. you need to upload an apk or android app bundle signed with your own certificate.

How can I change or resolve this issue?

Comment: have try again with new Keystore and create new SIGNED APK?

Comment: I guess you need the same key for updating an already published app. See link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file

Answer (score 0):

If your app is registered with Google Play App Signing you can follow [the instructions here, in the section "Create a new upload key"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) to let Google Play support help you create a new key.

If your app isn't registered with Google Play app signing and you have lost your signing key there is nothing you can do except create a new app. This is a good reason to enroll with Google Play App Signing.

Comment: Its first time I am going to upload this app on play store, I created and sign the apk with new signature using keytool, and zip aligned the apk but I am unable to upload on palystore again.

Comment: Once an APK is uploaded, you can't change key. You'll have to create your app again with a new package name.

Comment: I have changed new package name too but still same problem exists. What could be the main problem?

Comment: The Play store should give you an error when you upload. What is the new error?

Comment: Upload failed
We could not save your changes. Please try again. 

its the only error shown there. What could be this?

Comment: At this point you should contact Google Play support. This can be done via the Help "?" icon in the Play console