# How do I completely delete an app from android console?

Tags: android, google-play

I've lost the signing key of my app and now I would like to add an update of that app but because is different signing key it will not allow me. So I decided to create a new app but both apps now have the same package name. I would like to remove the app but not only from store with "Unpublish" option but to completely delete it. Is there an option for this or I have to create a new package name?

Comment: Did you tried resetting your existing app signing key with Google? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file

Comment: @digiwizkid I haven't but I will try it. I knew that once you lost it you are no longer able to reset it and you have to create a new app

Answer (score 1):

You can not delete an app from your console, unpublish only. If you lost your keystore, then contact the support team they will allow you to change the signing key for that app.